# Loop services from txt file, change startup type if needed and start if needed

Tags: powershell, foreach, service

i'm trying to create script that would loop all services listed in txt file, check if service startup type is right (if not change it) and start service if needed. I'm not that good with Powershell and would not really find anything usefully from Google.

My text file:

```
Service A
Service B
Service C
Service D
Service E
```

My current script look currently like this and at the moment I was able to print every single service from text file but lack information from next steps.

```
$services = Get-Content .\services.txt

## Pass each service object to the pipeline and process them with the Foreach-Object cmdlet
foreach ($service in $services) {
    
    Get-Service $service | Select-Object -Property Name, StartType, Status, DisplayName
    }
```

Hard thing is that every service don't have same startup type and status so it more complicated e.g

- Service A would need to be manual and running
- Service B would need to be Automatic and running
- Service C would need to be manual and stopped

So if service A are not Manual and running, script would change them and give information about change (write-host?).

I know what I can change Service startup type and Status with command set-service and list status with get-service but my skills are not enough yet to set that in script. Don't know if this even possible this way or are they better ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to change your services text file to a Csv file where you can not only list the service's Name, but also the desired StartType and Status like:

```
Service,StartType,Status
Service A,Manual,Running
Service B,Automatic,Running
Service C,Manual,Stopped
```

Then you could code it something like

```
Import-Csv -Path .\services.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $changed = $false
    $service = Get-Service -Name $_.Service
    if ($service.StartType -ne $_.StartType) {
        Write-Host "Changing StartType for service $($service.Name)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $service | Set-Service -StartupType $_.StartType
        $changed = $true
    }
    if ($service.Status -ne $_.Status) {
        Write-Host "Changing Status for service $($service.Name)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $service | Set-Service -Status $_.Status
        $changed = $true
    }

    # refresh the info if you changed anything above
    if ($changed) { $service = Get-Service -Name $_.Service }
    # write out current status
    Write-Host "Service: $($service.Name) - StartType: $($service.StartType) - Status: $($service.Status)"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `Select-Object`.  `Get-Service` accepts directly pipeline input for service names

```
$Services = Get-Content .\services.txt | Get-Service

ForEach( $Service in $Services )
{
    If( $Service.StartType -eq 'Manual' -and $Service.Status -eq 'Running' )
    {        
        Set-Service -InputObject $service -StartupType 'Automatic'
    }
    # Add more logic as needed here!
}
```

However, it's unclear from your question how you are going to make decisions about the services.  Of course some services should be manual, automatic, etc...  Are you looking to dictate the desired state based on the text file?

If so an easy solution may be to store the config in a CSV file. formatted like `<ServiceName>, <DesiredStartType>`.  Then we can reconfigure the code to apply the desired changes and give better feed back to the console.

**Update Based on Comments**

Since you OKed the csv file, and to further build on [@Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63135027/4749264) . Here is another approach using a CSV input file.  In this case I turned the input into a hash table after extracting the services.  This makes it easy to reference the desired configuration.

Assuming the same CSV layout from Theo's answer:

```
Service,StartType,Status
Service A,Manual,Running
Service B,Automatic,Running
Service C,Manual,Stopped
```

---

```
$DesiredConfig = Import-Csv c:\Temp\Services.csv
$Services      = $DesiredConfig.Service | Get-Service

# Flip config data to a dictionary
$DesiredConfig = $DesiredConfig | Group-Object -Property Service -AsHashTable -AsString

ForEach( $Service in $Services )
{   
    $DesiredStart  = $DesiredConfig[$Service.Name].StartType
    $DesiredStatus = $DesiredConfig[$Service.Name].Status

    If( $Service.StartType -ne $DesiredStart -or $Service.Status -ne $DesiredStatus )
    {
        Write-Host "Changing $($Service.Name) StartType/Status : $($Service.StartType) / $($Service.Status) > $DesiredStart / $DesiredStatus) ..."
        $Service = $Service | Set-Service -StartupType $($DesiredConfig[$Service.Name].StartType) -Status $DesiredStatus -PassThru
        # You don't need to reassign or use -PassThru, however if you are going to post-report this spares you the need to
        # re-get-services.  You are going to run the set command anyhow!
    }
}

# Not needed, but just to check...
$Services | Format-Table Name,Displayname,STartType,Status -AutoSize
```

I didn't test this, but the approach should be solid.

Let me know if that's helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I already know which services needs to be manual/automatic or if it needs to be running/stopped, so they could be stored in csv/text file. e.g "Windows Firewall" need to be "Running" and "Automatic" when "Plug and Play" needs to be "Running" and "Manual" and "Windows Update" need to be "stopped" and "Manual"

Comment: Service status and startup type are listed by vendor when installing spesific software